# System error Database 1/0 error

Tags: wallet, error

I just updated my btc wallet to 0.8.1, I think, to a macbook. Now I can't open it, I keep getting an error message that says "System error Database 1/0 error"?
I'm fairly technically illiterate so any help would be much appreciated.